# Several issues about deducing conversion function template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

The rules for deducing template arguments for the conversion function templates are in the section [temp.deduct.conv](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv).

The first rule designates what is the corresponding P and A, the first question is here:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing the return type of the conversion function template (call it P) with **the type specified by the conversion-type-id of the conversion-function-id being looked up (call it A)** as described in [temp.deduct.type]. If the conversion-function-id is constructed during overload resolution ([over.match.funcs]), the following transformations apply.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct C{
    template<typename Type>
    operator Type(){
        Type a{};
        /*a = 1;*/
        return a;
    }
};

int main(){
    int const& rf = C{};
}
```

For this example, P should be `Type` but what's the A? It seems there's only one rule related to it:
[over#match.funcs.general-7](https://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.funcs.general-7)

> In each case where conversion functions of a class S are considered for initializing an object or reference of type T, the candidate functions include the result of a search for the **conversion-function-id operator T in S**.

I don't know whether the A is only `int const&` here or **any of the permissible types** defined for this initialization.

If A is determined by the former, then P is `Type` and A is `int const&`.

According to bullet 2:

> If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used in place of P for type deduction and for any further references to or transformations of P in the remainder of this subclause.

Hence, the transformed P is still `Type`, then such a P/A pair will undergo bullet 3

> If A is not a reference type:
>
> > - [...]

Because A is of reference type, so skip bullet 3. Continue to bullet 4

> If A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of A's type are ignored for type deduction. If A is a reference type, the type referred to by A is used for type deduction.

Undergo bullet 4, now A is transformed to be `int const`.

Bullet 5 says:

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A **identical** to A. However, certain attributes of A may be ignored:
>
> > - If the original A is a reference type, any cv-qualifiers of A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference).
> > - If the original A is a function pointer or pointer-to-member-function type, its noexcept.
> > - Any cv-qualifiers in A that can be restored by a qualification conversion.

> These **attributes are ignored only if type deduction would otherwise fail**.

There's a question here, the [compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/a5qMnr) says the deduced A is `int`, However, IIUC, deduce `Type` from `const int`, Isn't the deduced type would be **const int**? why the deduced template argument is `int` rather than `const int`?

If change the conversion function template to

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct C{
    template<typename Type>
    operator Type&(){
        static Type a{};
        a = 1;
        return a;
    }
};

int main(){
    int const& rf = C{};
}
```

Then `Type` will be deduced to `const int`. Why the deduced type is different from the above example at this time? (They should have been the same result, which would be `const int`). Is anything I missed for deducing `Type` from "const int" in the first example?

Comment: Clang sources say [If A is a reference type, the type referred to by A is used for type deduction. We work around a defect in the standard here: cv-qualifiers are also removed from P and A in this case, unless P was a reference type.](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/979c38cc74f4e96c5e1bee1f966a81038fff1ed6/clang/lib/Sema/SemaTemplateDeduction.cpp#L4430-L4437)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So,  we can consider the second question is a defect of the current standard? How about the first question, I think the wording of the first rule for determining  `A` is so complex compared to the corresponding of c++17.

Comment: _I don't know whether the A is only int const& here or any of the permissible types defined for this initialization._ Why would it?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer  It says "the conversion-type-id of the conversion-function-id being looked up". For initializing reference of type `int const&`, the candidate for lookup not only contain `operator int const&()` but also `operator int&`. As said in [over.match.ref#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.ref#1). Moreover, for initializing an object of type int, the candidate should be looked up not only contain `operator int()` but also `operator cv int()` and `operator int cv&()` and `operator int cv&&()` as said in [over.match.funcs#general-7](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-7)

Comment: Are you get an answer to this question from somewhere? If possible, answer your question. Still, I need to know how to determine template arguments of a conversion function template.

Comment: @John As far as now, I haven't gotten accurate answers to this question.

Comment: More details can be seen at https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/123

Comment: "_As far as now, I haven't gotten accurate answers to this question._" So, can you update your question with the current draft and repost it to make it newly visible? I just don't need to create a new question talking about the same thing which likely might be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: _"More details can be seen at github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/123 "_ I don't think this is an issue by itself but I think there's a lack of detailed (good) explanation regarding what you're asking for. So, the deleted answer was relatively correct but it didn't so accurate and inconsistent