# Is this an issue in the template argument deduction process | Conversion function template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following example:

```
struct S
{
    template <class T>
    operator const T()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
} s;

int&& res = s;
```

Per [[temp.deduct.conv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#conv-1): (emphasis mine)

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing the return type of
> the conversion function template (call it `P`) with the type that is
> required as the result of the conversion (call it `A`) [..]

and [[temp.deduct.conv]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#conv-4): (**emphasis mine**)

> If A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of A's type
> are ignored for type deduction. **If A is a reference type, the type
> referred to by A is used for type deduction**.

and [[temp.deduct.conv]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.deduct#conv-5) (emphasis mine)

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument
> values that will make the deduced A identical to A. However, there are
> four cases that allow a difference:
>
> - (5.1) If the original A is a
>   reference type, A can be more cv-qualified than the deduced A (i.e.,
>   the type referred to by the reference).
> - [..]

I'm expecting either of the following is occurring:

- The types of `P` and `A` will be: `P = const T, A = int&&` Now, since `A` is a reference type, no adjustments occurred in `P`. But the type `A` would be adjusted per `[temp.deduct.conv]/4`. So the final types of `P` and `A` is `P = const T, A = int`. Now we've ended up with a deduction failure, so alternative deductions defined in `[temp.deduct.conv]/5` are considered. The bullet `(5.1)` is what's needed in this case. Now A (`int`) is not more cv-qualified than deduced A (`int`). So the program is ill-formed because the initialization is invalid.
- The reference initialization is invalid duto binding a reference of type `int&&` to a value of type `const T`will drop qualifiers. So the program is ill-formed because the initialization is invalid..

Unfortunately, nothing of what I expected happened. The [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b1r6d9nPf) clearly shows that the `deduced T` for the above example is `int`.

**My question**: What am I missing/conflating here?

Comment: Related/Dupe: [Deducing template argument of a conversion function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73376354/deducing-template-argument-of-a-conversion-function-template) and [Several issues about deducing conversion function template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574091/several-issues-about-deducing-conversion-function-template-arguments).

Answer (score -2):

N4861, to which you link, is not the newest working draft. I'm going to assume that you linked to it because it's the closest draft to C++20. The quotations that I'm going to provide below are from C++20 itself, just in case there are any differences.

According to [temp.deduct.conv]/1, we need to consult [dcl.init], [over.match.conv], and [over.match.ref] to determine what is `A`.

And in fact, [dcl.init] is really where you should have started looking in the first place, since the overload resolution is triggered by the declaration `int&& res = s;`.

[dcl.init.ref]/5.3 and 5.4 govern the initialization of rvalue references. 5.3 is tried first:

> Otherwise, if the initializer expression
>
> - is an rvalue (but not a bit-field) or function lvalue and "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv2* `T2`", or
> - has a class type (i.e., `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be converted to an rvalue or function lvalue of type "*cv3* `T3`", where "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv3* `T3`*" (see [over.match.ref]),
>
> then the value of the initializer expression in the first case and the result of the conversion in the second case is called the converted initializer. If the converted initializer is a prvalue, its type `T4` is adjusted to type "*cv1* `T4`" ([conv.qual]) and the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. In any case, the reference is bound to the resulting glvalue (or to an appropriate base class subobject).

So we need to consult [over.match.ref] to see if such a *cv3* `T3` exists (in which case the conversion will be performed, and `res` will be bound to the result of that conversion). *(Note that [over.match.conv] will not be reached in this case; it would be reached if we got to [dcl.init.ref]/5.4, but we will not, because [dcl.init.ref]/5.3 will succeed.)*

[over.match.ref] says:

> Under the conditions specified in [dcl.init.ref], a reference can be bound directly to the result of applying a conversion function to an initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select the conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that "reference to *cv1* `T`" is the type of the reference being initialized, and "*cv* `S`" is the type of the initializer expression, with `S` a class type, the candidate functions are selected as follows:
>
> - The conversion functions of S and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within `S` and yield type "lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`" (when initializing an lvalue
>   reference or an rvalue reference to function) or "*cv2* `T2`" or "rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`" (when initializing an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function), where "*cv1* `T`" is reference-compatible ([dcl.init.ref]) with "*cv2* `T2`", are candidate functions. For direct-initialization, those explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within `S` and yield type "lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`" (when initializing an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference to function) or "rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`" (when initializing an rvalue reference or an lvalue reference to function), where `T2` is the same type as `T` or can be converted to
>   type `T` with a qualification conversion ([conv.qual]), are also candidate functions.
>
> The argument list has one argument, which is the initializer expression.

The only type that `int` is reference-compatible with is `int` itself, and we are initializing an rvalue reference, so according to this section, we look for conversion functions of `S` with type `int` and `int&&`.

Only at this point, we are ready to perform template argument deduction under [temp.deduct.conv]/1. We will need to do this twice: once with `A` = `int`, and once with `A` = `int&&`. The results are then merged, and if there is more than one candidate in the resulting set, then we need to use overload resolution to select the one that gets called.

With `A` = `int`, [temp.deduct.conv]/3.3 tells us that the top-level cv-qualifiers of `P` are ignored. Clearly, this results in `T` being deduced as `int`; the candidate is `S::operator const int()`.

With `A` = `int&&`, in this case the top-level cv-qualifiers of `P` are not ignored; `P` remains `const T`. [temp.deduct.conv]/4 tells us that `A` is transformed into the type it refers to, namely `int`. We do the deduction using the transformed types (`P` = `const T`, `A` = `int`). This fails; there's no `T` such that `const T` is `int`. So there are no candidates generated in this step.

The result is that `S::operator const int()` is called, producing a prvalue of type `const int`, but cv-qualification of prvalues of scalar type is discarded prior to any further analysis. So it is materialized into a temporary object of type `int`, and `res` is bound to that temporary.

Comment: [Several issues about deducing conversion function template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574091/several-issues-about-deducing-conversion-function-template-arguments)

Comment: The standard clearly says in [temp.deduct.conv]/1 that the type of A is _the type that is required as the result of the conversion_ -  and the type that is required as the result of the conversion is `int&&` only. So why you said _".. we look for conversion functions of S with type int and int&&."_?

Comment: @John _the type that is required as the result of the conversion is `int&&` only_ Why are you so sure?

Comment: "_The only type that int is reference-compatible with is int itself, and we are initializing an rvalue reference, so according to this section, we look for conversion functions of S with type int and int&&._" How could you conclude this?

Comment: @John I feel that you must not have read my answer. [over.match.ref] tells you what type is required as the result of the conversion. It says that both "*cv2* `T2`" and "rvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`" are possibilities (when we are initializing an rvalue reference).

Comment: I just need you to simplify things a little bit. Consider a case that you have `A` is `const int&`. So I have to match `P` with `A = const int` and also with `A = const int&`. Then, if one of them yields deduction failure, there's no candidate generated for that type. The same process is performed if A is `const int&&`. Right?

Comment: `Then, if one of them yields deduction failure, there's no candidate generated for that type.` Assuming I'm correct. Are the alternative deductions considered after failing the usual deductions?

Comment: @John I'm not sure whether I understand your question. Are you asking about what happens when the type of the reference being initialized is `const int&`? According to [over.match.ref], since this is an lvalue reference, we only consider conversion functions that will yield "lvalue reference to *cv2* `T2`". However, there will be two possible values of "*cv2* `T2`": `const int` is reference-compatible with `int` and `const int`. So the two possible `A`'s in such a case are `int&` and `const int&`.

Comment: @John when [over.match.ref] yields multiple possible `A`'s, then yes, if any possible `A` results in deduction failure under [temp.deduct.conv], it generates no candidates. However, for any one particular `A`, we do have to consider [temp.deduct.conv]/5 before we determine that deduction has failed. The possibilities under [temp.deduct.conv]/5 were not relevant to your original question, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: @John If you have any more questions about how to interpret the wording of [over.match.ref], I would recommend that you add a new question, and specify precisely what part of the wording you need help with.